# In Typescript how to Ignore NPM package's built-in declaration file?

Tags: typescript

I'm using NPM package `react-hyperscript-helpers`. When I import it it'll read `index.js` and take the types from `index.d.ts`. These types however seem to be outdated since I get a lot of errors like this:

`node_modules/react-hyperscript-helpers/lib/index.d.ts(546,53): error TS2314: Generic type 'HTMLAttributes<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).`

I know how to fix the type errors but I cannot of course edit the file under `node_modules` because it would get overwritten in the next `npm install`.

**How do I ignore the included `.d.ts` file and use mine instead?**

I tried ignoring all of `node_modules` in `tsconfig.json` and setting the `typings` option but without any success. Here's that file if it's any use:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "jsx": "react",
        "typeRoots" : ["./typings"]
    },
    "include": [
          "typescript/**/*"
      ],
      "exclude": [
        "node_modules/**/*",
        "node_modules/react-hyperscript-helpers/lib/*.ts"
      ]

}
```

Comment: Maybe you can try with some paths options, check out https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First option:

Don't use @types npm modules and put all the declarations by hand in `d.ts` files that you include in your `tsconfig.json`. You'll have to wrap the definition with `declare module "mymod" {...}` for all pkgs.

Besides doing this make sure to add this compilerFlag in your config `"moduleResolution": "classic"`

Second option:

Vendor the whole npm pkg you want to correct the declarations for. You keep using @types pkgs but fix the one npm pkg not working for you.

Third:

Send a PR to the pkg creator.

This is actually the result of help of Arnavion in ##typescript in IRC freenode. Just posting it here for people with the problem.